# The file is not a valid VSIX package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix

After installing Visual Studio 2017, I was able to work on this Vs package for a month or so until the first update. Now after I rebuild this Visual Studio package, and then try to install the VSIX, I get a message saying that it is an "invalid VSIX package".

Any help or pointers would be appreciated...

[image]

EDIT:

The log shows this:

Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll'

> 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 19/03/2017 10:16:02
>   PM - ------------------------------------------- 19/03/2017 10:16:02
>   PM - vsixinstaller.exe version: 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - 15.0.26228.9
>   built by: D15RTWSVC 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - Command line parameters: 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Service\BSToolsProject_3\Tools\ProductivityTools\Bin
>   (Scenario Engine)\Capitec.ScenarioEngineExtension.vsix 19/03/2017
>   10:16:02 PM - ------------------------------------------- 19/03/2017
>   10:16:02 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - Failed to initialize settings for Isolated Shell C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe:
>   Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll'.
>   19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - Failed to initialize settings for Isolated
>   Shell C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe: Unable to find an
>   entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll'. 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM
>   - Initializing Install... 19/03/2017 10:16:02 PM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InvalidExtensionPackageException:
>   The file is not a valid VSIX package.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.ReadVSIXManifestFromPackage(Stream
>   stream, CultureInfo preferredCulture)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl..ctor(String
>   path, CultureInfo preferredCulture)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.CreateInstallableExtension(String
>   extensionPath, CultureInfo preferredCulture)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.CreateInstallableExtension(String
>   extensionPath)    at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String
>   vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the VSIX file contains the required files that make it  VSIX v3 file:

extension.vsixmanifest
manifest.json
catalog.json

And that the extension.vsixmanifest file contains a prerequisites section

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I tried following this guide, but after adding the nuget package and setting the property in the csproj the VSIX is still rejected by VS2017...

Comment: Feel free to share the VSIX

Comment: I'm trying to build Git Extensions to support VS2017. You can find my pull request here: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/3439

Comment: I have added a couple of comments to the pr - do not see the vsix version of the build tools nugget package being used either?

Comment: For future readers - this can occur when you build a v3 VISX with VS 2015/msbuild 14. Modifications to the csproj/command line can make this possible however

Comment: @Chriscan you please add details about what changes should I make to the csproj?

Answer (score 0):

(Applies to VS 2015)

The problem for me was the section

```
<Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0" Version="[12.0]" />
</Prerequisites>
```

in "source.extension.vsixmanifest" file.

After removing these lines, VSIX file started working.